# How to rename woocommerce order actions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to rename the wordpress woo-commerce orders actions **Processing orde**r to survey. I am not good in wordpress. Can some one tell me how can I achieve this. I tried google its only giving me to add customer order actions.

Answer (score 0):

> If you just want to change the display name then you have to use
>   [`wc_order_statuses`](http://hookr.io/filters/wc_order_statuses/) filter.

Here is the code:

```
function wh_process_to_survey($order_statuses)
{
    foreach ($order_statuses as $key => $status)
    {
        if ('wc-processing' === $key)
        {
            $order_statuses[$key] = _x('Survey', 'Order status', 'woocommerce');
        }
    }
    return $order_statuses;
}

add_filter('wc_order_statuses', 'wh_process_to_survey', 10, 1);
```

*Code goes in `functions.php` file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**Code is tested and works.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: I apologize for the late reply. I don't want to rename order status I would like to rename order actions "Processing order" word.

Comment: I cound not able to get you.